# pre-pared statement query not returning any results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to send some database row id's to another page, then use them id's to load the rows and process. I have used a session variable which works fine.

```
$_SESSION['tmp'] = "50,51,52";

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,jpg WHERE id = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$_SESSION['tmp']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($result_id,$result_jpg);
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $image = array($result_id => $result_jpg);
                print_r($image."<br />");
            }
        } else {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
```

The query would be

> SELECT id,jpg WHERE id = 50,51,52

which should return all of them rows, but instead nothing is being displayed at all, no errors or anything. Any ideas?

**######Edit#####**

Updated my code:

```
//Generate the query
    $query = "SELECT id,jpg FROM images WHERE id IN (?";
    for ($i=1; count($_SESSION['tmp']) > $i; $i++) {
        $query = $query.",?"; 
    } $query = $query.")";

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
        for ($i=1; count($_SESSION['tmp']) > $i; $i++) {
            $b = $_SESSION['tmp'][$i]-1;
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$b);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($result_id,$result_jpg);
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $image = array($result_id => $result_jpg);
                print_r($image);
            }
        } else {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
```

Can't seem to do the looping of

> bind_param("s",50);

as getting the error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
>   number of parameters in prepared statement in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\add_sales.php on line 39

**#####Edit 2#####**

Changed the way im going about this, this works fine.

```
$image = array();
    foreach($_SESSION['tmp'] as $x) {   
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,jpg FROM images WHERE id = ?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$x);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($result_id,$result_jpg);
            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                while($stmt->fetch()) {
                    $image[$result_id] = $result_jpg;
                }
            } else {
                echo "Prepare failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($image);
```

Comment: You haven't specified FROM which table to select.

Comment: prepared, not pre-pared.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have missed `FROM` clause
2. If you checked [`$mysqli->error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) you would have known it by yourself
3. `WHERE id = 50,51,52` is not a valid mysql syntax
4. You need to use `IN` operator instead
5. With prepared statements it will be evaluated as `WHERE id = '50,51,52'`. That's it - an `id` column is compared with a single string.

Comment: Can't believe I have just done that, how did I miss the FROM... thanks!

Comment: @Martyn Lee Ball: `FROM` is the least issue, take care on other points

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,jpg WHERE id = 50,51,52
```

Its wrong statement.

1) You can't write params in where so. 
Use `where id = 50 or id = 51 or id = 52`

2) you missed FROM: `FROM Table`

This is correct:

`SELECT id,jpg FROM table WHERE id = 50 or id = 51 or id = 52`

Comment: Crap! How did I miss that! Thanks

Comment: @Sharikov Vladislav: provide any number that is equal to `50` AND to `51` simultaneously.

Comment: @simult but you was right with `IN` clause. It is better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:
`SELECT id,jpg FROM tablename WHERE id IN (50,51,52);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind them all separately:

```
WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?)
```

And bind:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", 50);
$stmt->bind_param("i", 51);
$stmt->bind_param("i", 52);
```

You will want to use `explode()` and a loop to do it properly. You will also need to use implode to generate the right number of question marks:

```
$questionMarks = '(' . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($resultOfSplit), '?')) . ')';
```

Comment: Wouldn't I do `$stmt->bind_param("iii",50,51,52);`

Comment: @Martyn Lee Ball: it depends on if you have a static number of parameters

Comment: You can, but if your number params is variable (ie. you get it from the result of explode()), then you can't.

Comment: @Fabien Warniez: it also worth mentioning that for dynamic number of parameters you also need to generate a query correspondingly

Comment: The $questionMarks string is to be concatenated directly to the query, not bound through PDO. ie. `$query . $questionMarks`

Comment: I have done that, would it simply be easier to just loop the entire database call for each ID and get them seperatly, or is that slow on the system ? @FabienWarniez

Comment: I don't understand your comment.